# Firefox and SVG

Tags: firefox, svg

I have a web page that gets SVG content dynamically. The SVG content has a few defs which are used through xlink:ref to draw the actual content which are basically math expressions. Firefox 39 shows the math expressions properly but Firefox 43/44 do not show the math content unless the page is refreshed. Does anybody know if this is a bug in Firefox 43/44. I know we can use MATHML which is natively supported in Firefox but we are stuck with SVG coming from the server.

Comment: Raise a bug in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org). Don't forget to attach a [mcve] to the bug. Establishing a regression range using [-moz-regression](http://mozilla.github.io/mozregression/) would also be useful.

Comment: I've seen an odd problem before in code where the console.log func is actually causing a similar problem, so it may be worth double checking its not the logging causing an issue as opposed to browser svg implementation (I can probably dig out a workaround if so).

Comment: Ian, Thank you. I have a few console.log calls in the page but strangely the same code displays svg math expressions well. In Firefox 43/44 the mathml places appear as blank blocks. When page-refreshed, Firefox 43/44 shows the svg content